# How do i start a github java program?

Tags: java, github, compilation

I would like to start the program from this repository:
https://github.com/SaifurRahmanMohsin/Personal-Diary 
but when I dowload or clone it there is no Install file or no command in the readme file to compile it. 
How do I use it?

Comment: There is nothing like a "github java program". Github is a web-based hosting service for version control using GIT. The repository contains java files and all other resources you need to build the program. I don't see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is just a version control hosting service, so it's not a problem related to github but the project itself. 
Launcher.java have a main function, you need to run it to launch the project

Answer (score 0):

this project is not maven project, I think it will be best if you open it in eclipse and execute the Launcher (it has the main method for the execution)

Answer (score 0):

The repository includes a `.project` file for Eclipse. If you use this IDE you can import the project directly.

File -> Import -> General -> Existing project into workspace. Then select the `Personal Diary` folder which contains the `.project` file.

You can also compile manually using `javac`.